# What is meant by same parallel in the given theorem?

Tags: geometry

**Parallelograms on the same base and between *same parallels* are equal in areas**

Comment: Likely means that the sides opposite the ***same base*** lie on the ***same*** line, which must be parallel to the base of course. Given that parallel lines are at a constant distance, you have two parallelograms with equal bases and equal height.

Answer (score 0):

The figure illustrate the situation.

[image]

$f$ and $g$ are the two parallel lines and $AB$ is the common basis. The area of the parallegrams is $Area= a\cdot h$, where $h$ is the distance from the two parallel lines.

Answer (score 0):

Natural language tends to be ambiguous, which is a disadvantage. Using variables to clear up the ambiguities, the statement becomes

> Let $P_1$ and $P_2$ be parallelograms. Let $a$ be the base of $P_1$. Assume that $a$ is also the base of $P_2$. Let $\ell_1$ and $\ell_2$ be lines. Assume $\ell_1\|\ell_2$ and $\ell_1\ne \ell_2$. Assume that one edge of $P_1$ is on $\ell_1$. Assume that one edge of $P_1$ is on $\ell_2$. Assume that one edge of $P_2$ is on $\ell_1$. Assume that one edge of $P_2$ is on $\ell_2$. 
>   Let $A_1$ be the area of $P_1$. Let $A_2$ be the area of $P_2$. Then $A_1=A_2$.

Hm, I think natural language *does* have advantages ...

Comment: Yeah ok but i have a problem on this. If we took the contradiction of this statement that becomes as given below. "If the parallelogram which has same base and equal area then it lies between the same parallel". In this sense, Can we say the parallel line "l3 and l2 is same as l1 and l2". If so what will happen?